# I need to connect hibernate with mongoDB. Please provide the hibernate.cfg for mongoDB. I have one but its not working

Tags: java, mongodb, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-ogm

hibernate.cfg

```
<session-factory>

<property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider">MONGODB</property>
<property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.database">rcfdb</property>
<property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.host">127.0.0.1</property>
<property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.port">27017</property>

<property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">filesystem</property>    
<property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">./Indexes</property>    
<property name="hibernate.search.default.locking_strategy">single</property>
     <mapping resource="beanDao.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>
```

Getting error with the above hibernate.cfg. Unable to connect to mongoDB.

Comment: I have no knowledge of hibernate, but from what I can see your config lacks basic authentication parameters - username and password.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, you need to set the credentials and the authentication database; these are the properties:

```
hibernate.ogm.datastore.username
hibernate.ogm.datastore.password
hibernate.ogm.mongodb.authentication_database
```

You can find the list of properties for MongoDB in the official Hibernate OGM documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/ogm/reference/en-US/html_single/#_configuring_mongodb